# Understanding thread safe in web applications

Tags: java, multithreading, google-app-engine, servlets

I have brief understanding on Multi threading in java web apps( I know that servlet containers uses threading to serve same servlet to different requests in any application).

In our java web application, we have couple of servlet classes. In one  servlet I want to use this class  [BlobInputStream](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream) , but description of this class saying that it's not thread safe.

In my code I'm not creating any new threads explicitly, if I use this class in my code am I need to put synchronize blocks where I use this class.

**UPDATE**

following is my servlet code and I don't have any instance variables in   my servlet class

```
 @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
            Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
            List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myfile");
            BlobstoreInputStream inputStream = new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKeys.get(0));
            //this class implementing Runnable interface
            RunnableThread newThread = new RunnableThread(inputStream);
    }
```

any errors in the above code regarding thread safe

Comment: You need to worry about thread-safety only when you need to deal with `shared mutable` objects. If the objects are local variables like the ones you declare in your method (or) if the objects are immutable, then you don't have to worry about thread-safety.

Comment: Multiple threads need synchronized blocks if the **same** data structures are being accessed in the same time slot - does this help?

Comment: It depends on how you use `BlobInputStream`. If it's some instance variable in your servlet class, then you need to synchronize access to it, if it's a local variable created in your doGet/doPost methods, then it's not an issue.

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072798/java-web-development/write-thread-safe-servlets.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it in a servlet without synchronization, if you don't share the variable with other threads (e.g. make it an instance variable)

There's nothing wrong with having a servlet that creates a `BlobInputStream` (as a local variable), reads data and closes it.

Answer (score 0):

If `BlobInputStream` is an instance member of the servlet and since its not thread safe, you will have to use `synchronize` keyword but again it depends what operations are you performing using this class. If operations do not change state of any resource then there is no need to go for synchronization.

If its a local variable and you are not using any static method (which modifies state of the object) then you are safe. No need to use `synchronize` keyword.